# Digitizing parcel data and adding attributes to create interactive map

Tags: qgis, parcel

I am quite new to mapping and am attempting to learn by taking on an arbitrary little project (I also don't know how to code hope that's not going to be a problem). I want to create an interactive map that shows the residential parking permit zone along with relevant info such as time limit and enforcement details. Currently everything is static.

Data I have obtained:

1. City-wide RPP zone map in pdf (http://www.ci.berkeley.ca.us/uploadedFiles/Public_Works/Level_3_-_Transportation/RPP_R(1).pdf)
2. Parcels by RPP Area in gif (http://www.ci.berkeley.ca.us/Public_Works/Transportation/Residential_Parking_Permits.aspx)
3. Parcel data from the City's Open Data portal. I can export them into shapefile to be imported to either qgis or CartoDB (?)
4. All relevant info associated with each RPP Area such as time limits and enforcement hours.

So my questions are:

- Is there a way to merge these data together effectively?
- It looks like I can overlay the zone map (in pdf) over the parcel layer?
- If so, what tools do I use?
- Do I have to digitize the pdf first?
- How do I actually merge them and keep all the attributes?

Ideally I would want to have one layer for each zone, color coded, so I can turn them on and off.

I know how to create new layers by selecting features in ArcGIS (learned how to do that a long time ago in college), is it going to be similar in QGIS or in the other tools that you recommend?

My goal is for users to toggle over a location and know instantly the nearby parking restrictions.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user please take the [Tour] where you will see that there should be only one question asked per question.